# Reusable File Component using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a component called **BaseFile**

**components/BaseFile.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-group :label="label">
      <b-form-file
        :value="value"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        :accept="acceptedExtensions"
        @input="updateValue">
      </b-form-file>
    </b-form-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'BaseFile',
    props:   {
      label: { type: String },
      value: { type: Object },
      placeholder: { type: String, default: "Choose a file..." },
      acceptedExtensions: { type: String, default: "image/jpeg, image/png" }
    }, 
    methods: {
      updateValue(value) {
        // console.log(typeof value)
        // console.log(event.target.value)
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

then I'm calling this component in my **Users/new.vue**

```
<BaseFile label="Primary Image" v-model="primaryImage"/>

<script>
import BaseFile from "~/components/UI/BaseFile";
export default {
  components: {
    BaseFile
  },
  data() {
    return {
      profileImage: {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

when I try to add a file in BaseFile component, the error I'm getting is

```
 Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Object, got File.
```

I checked the documentation of Vue and there's no available props for `File`. But I need file because I'm uploading it directly to s3.

Comment: So the issue is that you're getting different value instead of a `File`? I actually tested this on my local and did not get this prop check warning.

Comment: I tried to do instanceof the value from updateValue method and I'm getting File. I tried adding File to the type of value and I'm getting `File is not defined`

Answer (score 3):

`Vuejs` will use instanceof for type checking.

So you can simply add `File` if you require both type:

```js
  export default {
    name: 'BaseFile',
    props:   {
      label: { type: String },
      value: { type: [Object, File] },
      placeholder: { type: String, default: "Choose a file..." },
      acceptedExtensions: { type: String, default: "image/jpeg, image/png" }
    },
  }
```

Also my advise would be to initialize `profileImage` with `undefined` or `null` IIUC you are not using it.

Comment: I'm still getting an error `File is undefined` when I add the type to [Object, File] and I changed the profileImage to null or undefined.

Comment: I made it work by not specifying the type for `value: {}`

Comment: Which browser are you using to have `File is undefined` ?

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you're expecting is of type `File` you can set the type to both `File` and `Object` by passing an array  like so

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'BaseFile',
    props:   {
      label: { type: String },
      value: { type: [Object, File},
      placeholder: { type: String, default: "Choose a file..." },
      acceptedExtensions: { type: String, default: "image/jpeg, image/png" }
    }, 
    methods: {
      updateValue(value) {
        // console.log(typeof value)
        // console.log(event.target.value)
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```